# What is the fastest and most resource efficient way to save a UIVIew as an image?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

We have a rather complex view hierarchy that is repeated many times on screen. To conserve resources when aloocating these views, we render them 1 time, save the to an UIImage, then save them to disk. The next time they are needed, they can be quickly pulled from disk rather than recreating them again. The method I am using to render the views right now is this (tile is the UIView object being passed in):

```
static CGFloat scale = -1.0;
    if(scale < 0.0){
        UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 4.0) {
            scale = [screen scale];
        }else{
            scale = 0.0;
        }
    }

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0);

    if(scale>0.0) // handling retina display
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    [tile.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();           
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage);

    success = [fileManager createFileAtPath:savePath 
                                   contents:imageData 
                                 attributes:nil];
```

This method works well, but it is the top resource hog in my app. According to Instruments, it consumes the most time and memory of anything during the run of the application. The main method call being pointed out is UIImagePNGRepresentation. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: UIImageJPGRepresentation is faster but you will be bound by -[CALayer renderInContext:]